# How to get a list of all fields with a specified attribute?

Tags: c#, attributes, field, roslyn

I am trying to find fields with a specified attribute. I tried to modify the FirstQuickFix example, because I thought, it could be a good starting point. But if I run the code, nothing happens. Any ideas what my major-problem is?

My understanding, after reading the Project Overview and the walkthrough-documents, is that I am able to request the attributes for a token, that I found in the syntax-tree. The syntax-tree is an exact tree-representation of the source-code. The connection of declaration of a field and its attributes is accessible via semantic. Or is my understanding totally wrong?

```
[ExportCodeIssueProvider("FirstQuickFix_", LanguageNames.CSharp)]
class CodeIssueProvider : ICodeIssueProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<CodeIssue> GetIssues
      (IDocument document, CommonSyntaxNode node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var tokens = from nodeOrToken in node.ChildNodesAndTokens()
                     where nodeOrToken.HasAnnotations(Type.GetType("myAttribute"))
                     select nodeOrToken.AsToken();

        foreach (var token in tokens)
        {
            var issueDescription = string.Format("found!!!");
            yield return new CodeIssue(CodeIssueKind.Info, token.Span, issueDescription);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

what I want to achieve, is to find ie. all fields with the attribute myAttribute:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        [myAttribute]
        string myField = "test";

        public void testing()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myField);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're confusing annotations and attributes. Annotations are a feature of Roslyn that can be used to mark some nodes in the syntax tree. They have nothing to do with attributes.

Comment: @svick thanks that is a good hint, but how do I access or find all fields with a specified attribute? I will add a example, what I trying to find to my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this, you can use LINQ to get all `AttributeSyntax` nodes with the specified name and then use `Parent` (twice) to get the node representing the field:

```
var fields = root.DescendantNodes()
                 .OfType<AttributeSyntax>()
                 .Where(a => a.Name.ToString() == "myAttribute")
                 .Select(a => a.Parent.Parent)
                 .Cast<FieldDeclarationSyntax>();
```

This is the most primitive version and works only on the syntactic level, so it won't work right if you have an attribute with the same name in another namespace, use the full name of the attribute (including namespace) or if you use `using` to refer to the attribute type using an alias.

If you want to support that, you will need to get the semantic model and then get the symbol representing the type of the attribute.

Comment: thanks @svick, that should be enough so far, but I just get the whole string `privat int myField = 0;` out of the `fields` variable... I do not see any object methods or properties, which could help me. But I am sure there must be an opportunity to access this information. Or do I have to go the semantic way therefore? Because I just need the field names... of course there are different quick and dirty solutions to get the field-name out of it, but I would prefere a good solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Anton You're not getting a `string` in that variable, you're getting a collection of `FieldDeclarationSyntax`es, which should be exactly what you need to get the information you want.

Comment: thank you very much! I tried to put the entries of the collection to access with an foreach-loop and don't gave the variable a specific type and just used var, so visual studio didn't give me the right attributes and methods of this FieldDeclarationSyntax ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For the edited example you provide, you can use a LINQ query in combination with the Type.GetField method:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class TestAttribute : System.Attribute { }

class State
{
    [Test] string name;
    [Test] string address;
    [Test] public string name2;
    [Test] public string address2;
    float height;
    public State(string name_, string address_, float height_)
    {
        name = name_;
        address = address_;
        height = height_;
        name2 = name_ + "2";
        address2 = address_ + "2";
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void ShowFields<T>(IEnumerable<T> fieldList)
    {
        foreach (var field in fieldList)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(field.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        State s = new State("Bob", "221 B Baker Street", 5.4f);
        System.Type stateType = typeof(State);
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] publicFieldList = stateType.GetFields();
        System.Console.WriteLine("----all public fields----");
        ShowFields(publicFieldList);

        System.Console.WriteLine("----all non public or instance fields----");
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] nonPublicFieldList;
        nonPublicFieldList = stateType.GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic| System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        ShowFields(nonPublicFieldList);

        var customAttributeFieldList = from t in stateType.GetFields()
        where t.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any(a => a is TestAttribute)
        select t;
        System.Console.WriteLine("----only public fields marked with a particular custom attribute----");
        ShowFields(customAttributeFieldList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is working code sample, to iterate over properties with custom attributes in a class.
You could use this an hint for "How to get a list of all fields with a specified attribute?".

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        var type = myClass.GetType();

        foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
        {
            //Get ALL custom attributes of the property
            var propattr = property.GetCustomAttributes(false);

            //Get MyAttribute Attribute of the Property
            object attr =
                (from row in propattr
                 where row.GetType() == typeof(MyAttribute)
                 select row).FirstOrDefault();
            if (attr == null || !(attr is MyAttribute))
                continue;

            var myAttribute = attr as MyAttribute;

            //output: NameAttrValue and AgeAttrValue 
            Console.WriteLine(myAttribute.Val);

            //Output: Name and Age
            Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    [My("NameAttrValue")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [My("AgeAttrValue")]
    public int Age { get; set; }


    public MyClass()
    {
        this.Name = "Jac";
        this.Age = 27;
    }
}

public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyAttribute(string val)
    {
        this.Val = val;
    }

    public string Val { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But I am a little bit confused, is it possible to integrate this example in my code? My mayjor-problem is, that I have never worked with attributes and roslyn before. How do I get n instance of the class in Roslyn? Do I have to go a way via document or node? I think it is really easy to achieve what I want, but I do not get it, sorry!

Comment: @Anton: I am not sure about your context and I am not familiar with Roslyn. 
I was trying to answer the second part of you question _"what I want to achieve, is to find ie. all fields with the attribute myAttribute:"_

Comment: @jacobaloysious Except the type is not from a compiled assembly, it's from a Roslyn syntax tree. And you can't use reflection for that.

Comment: @svick: I am not sure about Roslyn data structures/objects. I was trying to give an example to get an custom attribute of a property, nothing more.

Comment: @jacobaloysious My point is that that is not what the question is about, so your answer is useless here.

Comment: @svick: As i said in the previous comment, based on the title "How to get a list of all fields with a specified attribute?" I was trying to hit. Also i you check Anton's comment it say "I have never worked with attributes".
Experts like you might find it useless, probably amateurs like us could use it as a hint. Thanks for you comment.